# Disable or move the Chromium debug.log

Tags: jxbrowser

We notice that the chromium application within JxBrowser is writing a debug.log to the deploy directory.  Can we disable that log, or even better move that log to the cache directory (or another directory)?  This is within JxBrowser 4.9.

Thanks,

Matty

Answer (score 1):

By default, Chromium engine always creates the debug.log file in the same directory where Chromium binaries are located. In JxBrowser 6.x we implemented functionality that disables the debug.log file generation. Unfortunately, in JxBrowser 4.9 this functionality isn't available.